# jquery to only allow one rollover at a time

Tags: jquery, hover, slidedown, slideup

I created a `.slideDown` & `.slideUp` effect on a `div` based on `mouseover` and `mouseleave`.

The problem is that when I rollover multiple `divs` to fast then rolloff it seems to keep a memory of how many times I rolled over and will not stop until all of the slideDowns and slideUps are carried out.

Example: http://juliosalvat.com/IconTest/

Comment: Welcome to SO, Julio.  I edited your question a bit to include some code highlights and to remove unnecessary phrasing.  Hope that's ok!  Nice site you're working on BTW!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, this is A nasty one. Jquery keeps a queue of events, to short cut that queue you can use `.stop()`

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

What you'll probably need is `.stop(true, true)` which will remove all animation in the queue and just play the last one.

Comment: Matt, the way I have those drop down effects is through a jquery like accordian effect. $('div.AccountingButton').mouseover(function() {
        if (!dragged) $('div.AccountingContent').slideDown('normal');
    });       $('div.AccountingButton').mouseleave(function() {
         $('div.AccountingContent').slideUp('normal');       
    });  adding the stop to the end ?

Comment: Taking another look at your code you seem to have put yourself in a bit of a corner. Each button has it's own class and thus it's own set of JS for the animation. If I were you I would make all the buttons the same class so you only need to declare the animation code once. After doing that in the mouseover event callback I would select all the buttons and call a stop(true, true). So if you created a class called 'app_button' you could do $('app_button').stop(true, true) before doing a slide down to cancel out any queued up animation.

Comment: They all need to have there own class becuae they will be droping into the Android Simulator and each different icon will be filling the simulator with a different screen shot. I was able to gather all the classes for button and write one line of code like this. $('[class$="Button"]').stop(true,true); but it just stops from the animation from firing

Comment: I am using the .slideDown on mouseover of a div to trigger another div to move and slide down

Comment: $('div.AccountingButton').mouseover(function() {
        if (!dragged) $('div.AccountingContent').slideDown('normal');
    });

Comment: Matt thank you! I got it working by adding ".stop(true, true)" before .slideDown and .slideUp and also changing the mouse event to mouseover & mouseout instead of mouse enter and mouseleave. Thanks again.

Comment: Not a problem! Remember to select an answer to your question by clicking on the green check-mark.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the **HoverIntent** jQuery plugin

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

> hoverIntent is a plug-in that attempts to determine the user's
>   intent... like a crystal ball, only with mouse movement! It works like
>   (and was derived from) jQuery's built-in hover. However, instead of
>   immediately calling the onMouseOver function, it waits until the
>   user's mouse slows down enough before making the call.